# jQuery counting, rounding and ordering values

Tags: jquery, count, rounding

I am calculating 3 aspects (tables) of quotation and after submitting the form the offer is generated to PDF using TCPDF.

But there are few little problems about rounding values and counting separate VAT.

this is one of aspects / material with textarea, inputs and selects ->

```
<form action="pdf/gen-czk-pdf.php" method="get">
<table>
<tr>
<td><textarea name="materialItemName[]"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" class="jednotkovaCenaMaterialu" name="materialUnitPrice[]" value="0.00" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="pocetJednotekMaterialu" name="materialItemQuantity[]" value="1.00" /></td>
<td><select name="materialUnitType[]"><option value="m&#178;">m&#178;</option><option value="m&#179;">m&#179;</option><option value="bm">bm</option><option value="ks">ks</option><option value="kg">kg</option><option value="l">l</option><option value=" "> </option></select></td>
<td><input type="text" class="koeficientMaterialovePolozky" name="materialItemCoeff[]" value="1.00" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="celkemMaterialovaPolozkaBezDph" name="materialItemPriceNoVat[]" value="0" /></td>
<td><select class="dphPolozkaMaterial" name="materialItemVat[]"><option value="1.21">1.21</option><option value="1.15">1.15</option></select></td>
<td><input type="text" class="celkemMaterialovaPolozkaDph" name="materialItemSumVat[]" value="0" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="celkemMaterialovaPolozkaSDph" name="materialItemPriceInVat[]" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

AND SCRIPT ->

```
// countig material item price, no VAT
$('.jednotkovaCenaMaterialu, .pocetJednotekMaterialu, .koeficientMaterialovePolozky, .dphPolozkaMaterial, .celkemMaterialovaPolozkaBezDph').live('focus click keyup keypress blur', function() {
    var sumamaterialovapolozkabezdph = 0;
        $('.celkemMaterialovaPolozkaBezDph').each( function(key, val){
            sumamaterialovapolozkabezdph+= Number($($('.celkemMaterialovaPolozkaBezDph')[key]).val());
        Number($($('.celkemMaterialovaPolozkaBezDph')[key]).val(( Number($($('.jednotkovaCenaMaterialu')[key]).val()) * Number($($('.pocetJednotekMaterialu')[key]).val()) * Number($($('.koeficientMaterialovePolozky')[key]).val()))));
        var totalsumnovat = parseInt($('.materialCelkemBezDph').val())+parseInt($('.montazCelkemBezDph').val())+parseInt($('.vedlejsiNakladyCelkemBezDph').val());
            $('.total-sum').val(totalsumnovat);
// countig material item price, including VAT
    var sumamaterialovapolozkasdph = 0;
        $('.celkemMaterialovaPolozkaSDph').each( function(key, val){
            sumamaterialovapolozkasdph+= Number($($('.celkemMaterialovaPolozkaSDph')[key]).val());
        Number($($('.celkemMaterialovaPolozkaSDph')[key]).val(( Number($($('.jednotkovaCenaMaterialu')[key]).val()) * Number($($('.pocetJednotekMaterialu')[key]).val()) * Number($($('.koeficientMaterialovePolozky')[key]).val()) * Number($($('.dphPolozkaMaterial')[key]).val()))));
        var totalsumincludevat = parseInt($('.materialCelkemSDph').val())+parseInt($('.montazCelkemSDph').val())+parseInt($('.vedlejsiNakladyCelkemSDph').val());
            $('.total-sum-in-vat').val(totalsumincludevat);
    });
// section summary
    $('.materialCelkemBezDph').val(sumamaterialovapolozkabezdph)
    $('.materialCelkemSDph').val(sumamaterialovapolozkasdph);
    });
});
```

MY QUESTIONS ->

**1st question** How can I round summary values according following pattern? All values are unknown before of course.

**12205.12500 -> 12,205.13**

**12205.12499 -> 12,205.12**

summary values ->

```
$('.celkemMaterialovaPolozkaBezDph, .celkemMaterialovaPolozkaDph, .celkemMaterialovaPolozkaSDph')
```

**2nd question** How can I count separate VAT values?

VAT value ->

```
$('.celkemMaterialovaPolozkaDph')
```

The VAT value depends in pattern noted below

```
.jednotkovaCenaMaterialu * .pocetJednotekMaterialu * .koeficientMaterialovePolozky * (.dphPolozkaMaterial - 1)
```

I know my code isn't the best yet, but **I would appreciate any help. Thank you very much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for question 1: 
you can use

```
var num = 12205.12500;
num = Math.ceil(num * 100) / 100;
alert(num); // 12205.13;
```

Masking can be done easily as

```
var formattedString = parseFloat("1200000.15").toLocaleString()
```

formattedString will contain "12,205.13"

Comment: Thank you for your response Arun, I will try. My second question is how can I calculate the item (row) VAT sum
$('.celkemMaterialovaPolozkaDph')

something like
`.jednotkovaCenaMaterialu * .pocetJednotekMaterialu * .koeficientMaterialovePolozky * (.dphPolozkaMaterial - 1)`

Please ask me if its still incomprehensible

Comment: ok, class names are really big, try ask with sample code not with actual code.

Comment: And do you know how can I insert with JS `','` between every three numbers in result?

Comment: Thank you, I know it and I'm going to edit these classes soon

Comment: It's because of clarity

Comment: well best for comma separating values is jquery plugins, try http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney, it may helps you

Comment: I was try to implement jquery mask money (first example on the tut page). But I think it's not working with this lib `/1.8.3/jquery.min.js`
Is it possible?

Comment: versions could be issue, i never use it before but you can 1.9.0 as they used in tut

Comment: If i do, calculating is broken. Never mind. I'm going to try formattedString

Answer (score 0):

The javascript `Number` object as several usefull methods as `.toFixed()` that will set a fixed number of digit after the dot.

```
var x = new Number(123.568);
console.log(x.toFixed(1));
console.log(x.toFixed(2));
```

result will be

```
123.6
123.57
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp

You can also use `Math` libraries functions. There are 3 usefull functions, `.floor()`, `.round()` and `.ceil()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor